# Add custom react component as label in Dagre D3

Tags: reactjs, dagre-d3, dagre

I'm using dagre-d3 library for creating a flow path. I need to have custom component for every label but its not rendering react components, it however does render properly if the label is simple html. What do I need to do?
Following is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve, the first node should be the  component but its rendering a simple empty box in place of that:

[CodeSandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hertz-m7kj4)

Comment: I don't think the `dagre-d3-react` library you are using supports components as labels, however I do not think it would require a large code change so you might have some luck with a git issue.